# PayPal Recuring Payments Integration With Addons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a website where I sell software per user, where the client can select amount of users he needs to purchase. The question I have, is if the user originally purchased 10 users for $10 per user totaling $100 on March 1st. After that, on April 15th he decides to purchase another 5 users, so the total users would be 15, and the total per month would be $150.

How do we charge the user prorated price? How to modify the current subscription to include the prorated rate and keep recurring payments?

Answer (score 1):

With a current [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/) integration, [revise the subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions/) to a new Plan and have the payer approve it: via either the API response's returned url, or using the JS SDK's [actions.subscription.revise](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/#link-createsubscription) (recommended)

Comment: That really helped, thank you. I have another question, how do I include one time fee in the subscription when I modify it if it is not a set up fee? I want to prorate the user.

Comment: If you want to add a fee to the initial checkout, that *is* a setup_fee. If you want to lower the amount of the first payment, use a 1 cycle trial period for whatever lower amount.